# Possible to train classifiers in parallel on clusters?

Tags: neural-networks, svm, bagging, parallel-computing

Is it possible to train classifiers on data in parallel on supercomputer cluster? I think it makes sense when bagging. But what about in the case of something like SVM? Can this be only done by creating subsets of data? Does this tend to be easier with neural nets? If so, why?

Thanks!

Comment: Another presentation of distributed random forest: http://user2015.math.aau.dk/presentations/79.pptx

Answer (score 1):

The classifier training needs information from all training data so for bagging the training data is either replicated on processors or some reduced information is communicated if the data is distributed. Once the classifier is trained, the classifier is replicated and prediction can be parallel on different subsets of data.

See slides 34-38 in [this pdf](http://rbigdata.github.io/handouts/pbdr_ISM_HPCCON.pdf) for how to do this for random forest parallel training and parallel prediction with the randomForest package in R. Random forest classifiers are bagging plus random column subset selection.